# How do I measure execution time for each row in C#

Tags: c#, profiling, stopwatch

I have the following Selenium test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Edit()
{
    Driver.GoToAdministrera();

    Driver.ClickLink(strings.ActorSettings);

    Driver.SendKeysToId(text, "Attributes");

    Driver.Navigate().Refresh();

    Driver.AssertTextInId(string.Empty, "Attributes");

    Driver.SendKeysToId(text, "Attributes");

    Driver.ClickClass("submitbutton");

    Thread.Sleep(3000);

    Driver.Navigate().Refresh();

    Driver.AssertTextInId(text, "Attributes");
}
```

It is slow and I want to analyze where the bottleneck is. I know I could profile the test, but that will give me some long stack-trace and hotspots. I just want to know how long the execution time is for each row.

I know I can use the StopWatch class. I can even do something like a help method for this:

```
protected static void Time(Action action)
{
    var sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Reset();
    sw.Start();

    action();

    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed + " " + action.Method.Name);
}
```

But this requires me to modify my test.

Does anyone know of a method to get the timings for each row in a piece of code executed?

Comment: If you use Visual Studio 2012 or newer for development, why don't you use inbuilt tools for analyzing code and profiling the app?

Comment: That will give me some long stack-trace and hotspots. I just want to know how long the execution time is for each row.

Comment: If you use that profiler, just look for the inclusive percents of each of your routines above. That profiler has a downside - it discards samples during I/O or other blockage, so if that's the reason for slowness, it won't show it. Instrumentation mode might be good enough for you, though it loses line-level information. A method that always works is [*this one*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/378024/23771).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Visual Studio 2015 or later you can run the test under debugger and look for [PerfTips](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2014/08/18/perftips-performance-information-at-a-glance-while-debugging-with-visual-studio/) values. Stepping from line to line you will get estimated value of elapsed time for each line of the test which is probably what you need.

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
// Do Processing
Driver.GoToAdministrera();
DateTime end = DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine("Time taken : " + (end - start));
```

Comment: Yes that works but it requires me to modify my test.

Comment: `Stopwatch` will be a *better* choice then `DateTime`